# how to display an array with brackets in IOS?

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I have this code that gets email from database and use the emails as parameters to be passed in an NSDictionary.

```
NSMutableArray *newEmails = [NSMutableArray alloc]init];
newEmails = [[DBManager getSharedInstance]emails]; //get all emails from DB

NSDictionary *params =@{@"api_key":@"APIKEYIOS",@"action":@"get-message",@"email":[newEmails description]};
```

But it returns like this

```
params: {
    action = "get-message";
    "api_key" = APIKEYIOS;
    email = "(\n    \"yahoo@yahoo.com\",\n   \"gmail@gmail.com\"\n)"
```

How can I display the arrays like this:

```
["yahoo@yahoo.com", "gmail@gmail.com"]
```

Thanks for responses :)

Answer (score 0):

You should have to use

```
@"email":newEmails
```

not

```
@"email":[newEmails description]
```

`description` method gives you information about that element.

Comment: yhup. but its return is:
(
"yahoo@yahoo.com",
 "gmail@gmail.com"
)

Comment: I need like this: ["yahoo@yahoo.com", "gmail@gmail.com"]. Brackets not parenthesis. thanks for response by the way.

Comment: @meda I did it like this 
NSDictionary *params =@{@"api_key":@"APIKEYIOS",@"action":@"get-message-status",@"email":_emailsInApi};
    
    NSData *paramsData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params options:0 error:nil];

Comment: @teach I got you why you are saying about `(`, the problem is in Log window array values are display in `(` and not in `[`. So use the given answer. Don't just get confused by NSLog results.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar yah. I did put the newEmails. and the log is with parenthesis. The API returns "Some emails are not valid". It's because the format has to be the emails are in brackets not parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

You need to serialize you data into json format

```
NSData *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params  
                                                    options:0 
                                                      error:nil];
```

Then send `jsonArray` to your server

Comment: yhup. I did it like this NSDictionary *params =@{@"api_key":@"APIKEYIOS",@"action":@"get-message-status",@"email":_emailsInApi‌​}; NSData *paramsData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params options:0 error:nil];

Comment: are arrays in JSON need to be in this format? ["yahoo@yahoo.com", "gmail@gmail.com"] with brackets? or I can just put the name of the array?

Comment: you have to send `jsonArray` to your server not `params`

Comment: @meda OP got confused because of NSLog result.

Comment: @meda yah. I'm sending the jsonArray. I'm just asking how to put brackets. hehe because the response of API is "Some emails are not valid". It's because the format has to be the emails are in brackets not parenthesis.

Comment: What do you see on your php server